# Why serverfault about us leads to stackoverflow about us?

Tags: support, bug

When I open **about us** item in help menu in serverfault, it leads me to https://stackoverflow.com/company/about
Is this a mistake or something?
Edit. Same thing about **business** item. http://business.stackoverflow.com/?ref=topbar_help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is correct. Serverfault is a part of the [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/) network which is run by a company [named StackOverflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/).

This link is clearly labeled as "Learn about StackOverflow the company".

Comment: I was thinking main company is stack exchange. Thanks for clear answer.